# Integrating slack with github to get notifications on push happening to specific branch

Tags: github, slack

I am looking for a way how i can get a message to slack channel when a push happens in specific branch of github repo.

I tried doing it with below mentioned steps -

```
1. Installed github app in slack.
2. Added github to slack channel using /github.
```

After that when i try connecting to repository, github asked to authenticate. When i tried to do so it is navigating me to github.com instead of custom github domain of the company.

Please help me here.

Comment: https://github.com/rajsingh8220/Slack-Channel-Operations

Answer (score 1):

You could add to your repository a [`.github/workflows`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/configuring-a-workflow) in order to use a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions) (which is also [available for GitHub Enterprise](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/about-github-actions), not just github.com)

For example:

- [`pullreminders/slack-action`](https://github.com/pullreminders/slack-action)

> An action which wraps the Slack chat.postMessage API method for posting to channels, private groups, and DMs.
>
> This action sends messages using Slack bot tokens, which have two main advantages compared to user tokens and incoming webhooks:
>
> 1. Bots can't be disabled inadvertently when a Slack user is disabled or removed. Slack has written about this in a recent announcement, and
> 2. Bots offer a powerful range of capabilities that can be leveraged to perform more functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Drone continuous integration system in place you can use a webhook to trigger sending a Slack notification. This would work for the repository `.drone.yml` file:

```yaml
  - name: slack
    image: plugins/slack
    settings:
      webhook: https://hooks.slack.com/services/...
      channel: my_awesome_channel
      username: Github Bot
    when:
      event: [ pull_request ]
      branch: [ dev, master ]
    template: |
        New Pull Request Opened By: {{build.author}} ({{repo.name}} / {{build.branch}})
        {{build.link}}
```

This assumes that drone is already enabled and the webhook configured in Github. If it isn't you can enable it through the Drone web dashboard by navigating to `Repositories` and clicking the green switch next to your repo name.

Answer (score 0):

For custom github domain of company you need to use slack app (Githhub Enterprise Server) instead of Github App.
Once you are done with installation of Githhub Enterprise Server App on slack , Under configuration you will se payload url. Copy payload URL and go to github repository settings add webhooks sections and add payload url there and keep content type application/json